# Island Perimeter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/island-perimeter/)

> You are given a map in form of a two-dimensional integer grid where 1
>   represents land and 0 represents water.
>
> Grid cells are connected horizontally/vertically (not diagonally). The
>   grid is completely surrounded by water, and there is exactly one
>   island (i.e., one or more connected land cells).
>
> The island doesn't have "lakes" (water inside that isn't connected to
>   the water around the island). One cell is a square with side length 1.
>   The grid is rectangular, width and height don't exceed 100. Determine
>   the perimeter of the island.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> [[0,1,0,0],
>  [1,1,1,0],
>  [0,1,0,0],
>  [1,1,0,0]]
> ```
>
> Output: 16
>
> Explanation: The perimeter is the 16 yellow stripes in the image
>   below: [image]

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
  const getWaterNeighborAt = position => {
    if (!grid[position.y][position.x]) { return 0; }

    const north = position.y - 1 < 0 ? true : grid[position.y - 1][position.x] === 0;
    const east = position.x + 1 >= grid[0].length ? true : grid[position.y][position.x + 1] === 0;
    const south = position.y + 1 >= grid.length ? true : grid[position.y + 1][position.x] === 0;
    const west = position.x - 1 < 0 ? true : grid[position.y][position.x - 1] === 0;

    return north + east + south + west;
  };
  let perimeter = 0;
  grid.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((_, x) => {
      perimeter += getWaterNeighborAt({x, y});
    });
  });
  return perimeter;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Objects should be making the code easier to read. The Object you name `position` provides no behavioral benefit and serves only to bloat the code.
- You should be using good old for loops for this rather than the hacky way you use the array iteration function `forEach`
- Use function declarations `function islandPerimeter(grid)`. Do not use function expressions `var islandPerimeter = function(grid)`

### Rewrite

Rewriting your coder I would do it as follows

```
function islandPerimeter(grid) {
    const W = grid[0].length, H = grid.length;
    const countEdges = (x, y) => {
        var res = 0;
        if (grid[y][x]) { 
            res += y - 1 < 0 ? 1 : grid[y - 1][x] === 0;
            res += x + 1 >= W ? 1 : grid[y][x + 1] === 0;
            res += y + 1 >= H ? 1 : grid[y + 1][x] === 0;
            res += x - 1 < 0 ? 1 : grid[y][x - 1] === 0;
        }
        return res;
    };
    var perimeter = 0, x = 0; y = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < H; y ++) {
        for (x = 0; x < W; x ++) {
            perimeter += countEdges(x, y);
        }
    }
    return perimeter;
}
```

### A flaw in the problem

The question states all the land is connected which hints at an optimal solution however the problem is flawed.

There is a solution that is \$O(l)\$ where \$l\$ is the land cell count if you had one extra tit-bit of information, a coordinate of a land cell.

That way you could use a flood fill and thus only need to check land cells.

Without that coordinate  you need to search for the land and the worst case would have the land cell the last cell making it \$O(n)\$ where \$n\$ is the cell count.

### Performance

You can however improve the performance by counting edges as you cross them. If a cell is different than the cell to the left, or above then there is a edge to count

```
function islandPerimeter(grid) {
    const W = grid[0].length, H = grid.length;
    var x = 0, y = 0, res = 0, prevRow = 0, prev;
    while (y < H) {
        x = prev = 0;
        const row = grid[y];
        const prevCount = res;
        while (x < W) {
            const cell = row[x];
            res += cell !== prev;
            res += prevRow && prevRow[x] !== cell;
            prev = cell;
            x++;
        }
        res += prev;
        if (res && prevCount === res) { return res }
        prevRow = row;
        y++;
    }
    while (x--) { res += prevRow[x] === 1 }
    res += prevRow[0];
    return res;
}
```

As the question states that all he land is connected thus I added an early exit if there is an empty row after some land cells have been found.

### Flood Fill

And here is a flood fill example. Its just a quick write as it does not really provide an improvement without at least a coordinate of a land cell. There are a few optimizations that could be added and it also needs to modify the map so to not repeat cells

It finds the first cell by stepping over empty cells.

```
function islandPerimeter(arr) {
    const H = arr.length, W = arr[0].length, SIZE = H * W;
    const EDGES = [[1, 0], [-2, 0], [1, -1], [0, 2]];
    const stack = [];

    const isLand = () => (cell = arr[y] && arr[y][x] || 0) > 0;
    const isLandIdx = () => (x = idx % W, y = idx / W | 0, isLand());
    const checked = () => (stack.push([x,y]), arr[y][x] = 2);
    var x, y, res = 0, idx = 0, cell;
    while (idx < SIZE && !isLandIdx()) { idx++ }
    if (idx < SIZE) {
        checked();
        while (stack.length) {
            [x, y] = stack.pop();
            for (const e of EDGES) {
                x += e[0];
                y += e[1];
                isLand() ? (cell === 1 && checked()) : res++;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why not use function expressions?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Because they are more verbose and because they only become available after the expression, while declared functions are available anywhere and any time (after parsed) in the scope they are in.

Comment: `Objects should be making the code easier to read`: Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob) once mentioned that ideally functions should have only one parameter. I tried to follow that. Would you still advice against it?

Comment: `y - 1 < 0 ? 1 : grid[y - 1][x] === 0;`: Do you think this is a good style to mix `Number` and `Boolean` a value can take? It's working because addition/subtraction converts `Boolean` values to `Numbers`. But I got the impression that's kind of messy.

Comment: `const W = grid[0].length, H = grid.length;`: Why did you wrote `W` and `H` in capital letters? Because they are constants?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Re `W`,`H`  its a habit of mine, yes they are const but i used to do it for vars as well.  The number in the ternary means that it does not need to be coerced (should both not be numbers not bools?) One parameter! that does not means make objects to keep to the one parameter guide. Personally I would have let closure handle the variables rather than pass them as in the last example

Comment: What was actually your reasoning for writing `H = grid.length;`? I assume it is more concise and not because of performance concerns? `grid.length` is an attribute and accessing `length` doesn't cost much, does it?

Comment: Why do you think I used the forEach in a hacky way?

Comment: @thadeuszlay The `W,H` where used to keep the layout of the code neat. The use of the `_` to soak up an argument in the hack.